# ssh2_scp_send() returning "Failed to open stream: No such file or directory"

Tags: php, csv, ssh

Today I'm battling against ssh with huge success if it wasn't for ssh2_scp_send() method. This is the first time I work integrating ssh with PHP, so you may find multiple erros in the code that I have yet to discover, since I am currently stuck at that part.

I am using a dummy array imitating the one I must get from a couple of forms and the auth is working fine, although I had a little problem back there given that I had to use 'root' as user for the public key to be recognised as correct when comparing against, instead of my actual user.
Once I solved that matter, I discovered that the code is not working properly, this time the console says:

> ssh2_scp_send(tmp/sshPm/prueba1.csv): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/josemaria/Desktop/API UBcloud/CSV/provisioning.php on line 32

Here is my code:

```php
function arrayToCsv($array, $filename, $delimiter = ';'){

    header('Content-Type: application/csv');


    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'";');

    $f = fopen('/tmp/sshPm/'.$filename, 'r');


    foreach ($array as $line) {
        fputcsv($f, $line, $delimiter);
    }
} 



function connectSsh($filename){
    $sshConnection = ssh2_connect($host, $port);

    if (!$sshConnection) {
        die('Conexión Fallida');
    }

    ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($sshConnection, $user, $pubKey, $priKey);

    ssh2_scp_send($sshConnection, "/tmp/sshPm/$filename", '/home/scripts/CSV', 0644);

    $stream = ssh2_exec($sshConnection, "/home/scripts/sc_prov_ovpn_firm.sh $filename");

    ssh2_exec($sshConnection, 'exit');

    return $stream;
}



for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) { 

    $array[] = array(
        "VAAAAAGH", 
        "THE WAGH IS HERE", 
        200 + $i, 
        564451 +$i, 
        "sip",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "8.8.8.8",
        "8.8.4.4",
        20048,
        "Modelo Terminal",
        "677shdG3"
    );
}

$filename = 'test.csv';


arrayToCsv($array, $filename);
$stream = connectSsh($filename);
print_r($stream);
```

As you can see, I intend the CSV's to be created and stored in /tmp. Even though the csv is created and placed in the right directory, whenever I reach scp_send, this method proves incapabe of finding it. I don't know if this could be related to the fact that I am using root to veify my public key as I've seen that it should be the user you are logged in with.

I also get the following warning right inmediately, but I guess this is consecuence of the first one... In any case, here it is:

> PHP Warning:  ssh2_scp_send(): Unable to read source file in /home/josemaria/Desktop/API UBcloud/CSV/provisioning.php on line 32.

I have tried using a wrapper instead of fopen() but with no success. As I said, this is the first time I work using ssh and PHP so I would ask you to explain a little bit at least!
Thank you so much for the help!

**UPDATE**

I managed to solve partially the issue by following ArSeN's advice and creating a directory in /Desktop and changing all the routes to that one, instead of /tmp. Now the problem I face is that I am not sure where to place the files once created. So my next question related to this issue would be:

Where should I store all the CSV's generated locally? As you see, I am doing it in /Documents since I have no restrictions there to read/modify, but I would say the answer lies in /, maybe /var? I really have no clue about much of this stuff...

Thank you again for the help provided!

This is what my code looks like now:

```php
function arrayToCsv($array, $filename, $delimiter = ','){

    header('Content-Type: application/csv');


    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'";');

    $f = fopen("/home/josemaria/Documents/sshPm/$filename", 'w');


    foreach ($array as $line) {
        fputcsv($f, $line, $delimiter);
    }

    fclose($f);
} 



function connectSsh($filename){
    $sshConnection = ssh2_connect($host, $port);

    if (!$sshConnection) {
        die('Conexión Fallida');
    }

    ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($sshConnection, $user, $pubKey, $priKey);

    ssh2_scp_send($sshConnection, "/home/josemaria/Documents/sshPm/$filename", "/home/scripts/CSV/$filename", 0644);

    $stream = ssh2_exec($sshConnection, "/home/scripts/sc_prov_ovpn_firm.sh $filename");

    ssh2_exec($sshConnection, 'exit');

    return $stream;
}



for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) { 

    $array[] = array(
        "VAAAAAGH", 
        "THE WAGH IS HERE", 
        200 + $i, 
        564451 +$i, 
        "sip",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "8.8.8.8",
        "8.8.4.4",
        20048,
        "Modelo Terminal",
        "677shdG3"
    );
}

$filename = 'test.csv';


arrayToCsv($array, $filename);
$stream = connectSsh($filename);
print_r($stream);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my issue had to do with permissions. I had some other errors as @ArSeN pointed out, but the warning I got and which prevented the code to work was because I was trying to store and read the files in /tmp withouth the permissions required to do so. So give yourself full permissions on the dir or change the dir for another. I still have some problems and issues with this code, but I do feel that they belong to  a separate question that I will be linking here: [How can I generate a CSV on Win and Linux using PHP and ProcessMaker? Which paths are reccommended to store the files locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60095219/how-can-i-generate-a-csv-on-win-and-linux-using-php-and-processmaker-which-path)

Answer (score 1):

You should close the file handler so the file does actually get written and is not in some I/O buffer.

```
function arrayToCsv($array, $filename, $delimiter = ';'){
    // all your existing code here ...    
    fclose($f);
}
```

Also with your copy target it seems like you are putting a file where a folder is before, meaning:

```
ssh2_scp_send($sshConnection, "/tmp/sshPm/$filename", '/home/scripts/CSV', 0644);
```

should probably be:

```
ssh2_scp_send($sshConnection, "/tmp/sshPm/$filename", "/home/scripts/CSV/$filename", 0644);
```

Comment: Hi @ArSeN! thank you for your answer. After doing all the changes you suggested, the issue persists, with the cli showing me both warnings still. I am really new to ssh and even Linux. It seems that, as it's name would suggest, /tmp deletes all directories in between boots, I am wondering if this has something to do. It could be something related to permissions maybe? Where should I store the CSV's while they are sent to the remote server?